# Detect input coming from which barcode scanner in Java

Tags: java, usb, usb4java

hope all of you will be fine , i am working on java  , i have two barcode scanner attached to PC ,i want to detect either input coming from which barcode scanner 1 or barcode scanner 2 ,is there any possibility ,i have tried usb4java lib but unable to achieve this,i only get vendor and product of device but i dont know what to do further,here my code is to get vendor and product

```
    DeviceList list = new DeviceList();
        result = LibUsb.getDeviceList(context, list);
        if (result < 0)
        {
            throw new LibUsbException("Unable to get device list", result);
        }

        try
        {
            // Iterate over all devices and list them
            for (Device device: list)
            {
                int address = LibUsb.getDeviceAddress(device);
                int busNumber = LibUsb.getBusNumber(device);
                DeviceDescriptor descriptor = new DeviceDescriptor();
                result = LibUsb.getDeviceDescriptor(device, descriptor);
                if (result < 0)
                {
                    throw new LibUsbException(
                        "Unable to read device descriptor", result);
                }
                System.out.format(
                    "Bus %03d, Device %03d: Vendor %04x, Product %04x%n",
                    busNumber, address, descriptor.idVendor(),
                    descriptor.idProduct());
            }
```

Comment: Please describe what you have tried and what errors you are receiving. The models of your scanners could help too. As it is, the question is near unanswerable.

Comment: @Torben i edited my post kindly check there